# Centos 7: symbol lookup error: /lib64/libpango-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: fribidi_get_par_embedding_levels_ex

Tags: centos7

it seems that there are 2 version of fribidi on the system, how can i get rid of the old one?

```
/usr/lib/libfribidi.so.0
/usr/lib/libfribidi.so.0.3.6
/usr/lib64/libfribidi.so.0
/usr/lib64/libfribidi.so.0.4.0
/usr/local/lib/libfribidi.so.0
/usr/local/lib/libfribidi.so.0.3.6
/usr/local/src/fribidi-0.19.7/lib/.libs/libfribidi.so.0
/usr/local/src/fribidi-0.19.7/lib/.libs/libfribidi.so.0.3.6
```

Please help me. Thanks.